# Find records based on weight range stored in another table

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have two tables: `fighters` and `weight_divisions`. My `weight_divisons` table looks like this:

```
id | name              | upper_limit
====================================
1  | Flyweight         | 125
2  | Bantamweight      | 135
3  | Featherweight     | 145
4  | Lightweight       | 155
5  | Welterweight      | 170
6  | Middleweight      | 185
7  | Light Heavyweight | 205
8  | Heavyweight       | 265
```

And then my `fighters` table looks like this:

```
id | name          | weight
===========================
1  | Rob Sinclair  | 155
2  | Mark Adams    | 145
3  | Jack Marshamn | 185
```

What I'm wanting to do is select fighters by passing the ID of a weight category. I had one query which selects all fighters that are *under* the upper limit of a category…

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `fighters`
WHERE
    `weight` <= (
        SELECT
            `upper_limit`
        FROM
            `weight_divisions`
        WHERE
            `id` = :weight_division
    )
ORDER BY
    `name` ASC
```

…However, I also want to use the next lowest weight category's upper limit as a lower limit.

For example, if I specify `4` (Lightweight), it should select all fighters who are 155 or under, but also over 145 (Featherweight's `upper_limit`, Featherweight being the next lowest weight division). In the case of Flyweight, use 0 as a lower limit.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @eggyal I'd rather not, just to keep the data integrity intact. For example, I don't want it possible for a weight division's lower limit to be altered without also affecting the previous weight division's upper limit, leaving a possible void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can self-join the `weight_divisions` table to itself in order on a condition that one side of the join has a lower `upper_limit` than the other, group by the other side of the join and select `MAX(upper_limit)` of the lower side of the join to obtain the lower and upper weight bounds of each division.

Then one merely need join the result with the `fighters` table and filter appropriately:

```
SELECT fighters.*
FROM   fighters
  JOIN (
    SELECT   IFNULL(MAX(l.upper_limit),0) AS lower_limit, u.upper_limit
    FROM     weight_divisions l
      RIGHT JOIN weight_divisions u ON l.upper_limit < u.upper_limit
    WHERE    u.id = 4
  ) w ON w.lower_limit <= fighters.weight AND fighters.weight < w.upper_limit
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1294e/1/0).

Comment: Thanks, @eggyal! Looks like it's the basis of what I need. What will happen if I specify Flyweight though? Will the join fail with there being no lower weigh divisions?

Comment: @MartinBean: Quite right.  Use an outer join, as corrected above.